# I'd like to send a "Fire and Forget" query to a PHP page

Tags: php, asp.net, html, http

I'm implementing various PHP & ASP.NET web apps for a client.

I'd like to install a very low overhead user tracking system. (It has to be on the intranet, this is an internal system only).

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
line 1  normal code
line 2  normal code
line 3  Send Request/Query/Info to http://internal-IP/userTracker.php?Name=UserName&Page=...
line 4  Code that proceeds immediately after line 3 without waiting for a reply of any sort.
```

"Fire and Forget" seems to be the best analogy here.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Typically, tracking systems aren't called until the very end of the page, so you don't have to worry about waiting for a reply.  Is there a reason you can't do this?

Comment: If my requirement of not having to wait for a reply is met, then I can place my tracking requests anywhere I want, even in a php-include page, or within an Custom ASP.NET Control. True, in my specific situation I don't need to do this, but I like to learn things in as robust a manner as possible so as to save myself from future trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's pretty much a textbook case for AJAX.  Essentially, you fire off a rqeuest to that URL, and code execution continues as normal.

Here's an example in jQuery (assuming you want to post to the URL).  Other libraries may vary. As will doing so without any js lirbaries.

```
 //some code
 $.get("http://internal-IP/userTracker.php?Name=UserName", function() {
    //put something here if you want to verify the request worked.
 });
 //some more code
```

The browser will fire off the request, and "some more code" will continue executing without blocking on the request.

Comment: I'm already using jquery for some things such as dialogs and calendar controls. Is this get() function built into the standard jquery javascript files? Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3):

theory one: don't even bother doing the request with server code if you can avoid it. typically, people use invisible "tracking images" where it's just an <img> tag with src="http://internal-IP/userTracker.php?Name=UserName&Page=...". this avoids security headaches trying to get your webserver communicating with the tracking server directly. it's also better than ajax because it works across any combination of domains. the problem with either tracking images or ajax is if you don't want your users hitting the tracking server directly and would rather just ping server-to-server...

theory two: avoid AJAX and IMGs and just go server-to-server like you originally suggest. this is probably the better suggestion. are you writing this in .NET and having it fire off to a PHP page? if so, the .NET code above will work great. even though you don't care about the response, i'd still wrap the hell out of it with exception handling.

that's all i've got. :) good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I feel kinda dumb for not remember the IMG method. I know advertisers use the hell out of it for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 2):

For asp.net, you can use an asychronous web request and just have a dummy method that does nothing when the request comes back to you (maybe you want to check to make sure it returned status 200?).

Here's a C# example if you wanted to do this in the code behind, but the example posted by thedz would work for both ASP.NET and PHP pages.

```
void SendRequest(string uri)
{
    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseReceived), null);
}
void ResponseReceived(IAsyncResult result)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Any advantages to this over jquery or IMG tags?

Comment: If the rest of your site is in ASP.NET and your doing additional work on the back end, this is easier to maintain and can lead to more control down the road.  The disadvantage however is that the request will appear to be coming from your server rather than the client accessing your server, so really it all depends on what your fire-and-forget needs to do.  If you're recording client information, use the IMG tag.  If you think you'll ever need a response back, use the jquery.  If you want to hide the pixel hit from your users, use the code behind.

Comment: This will be more reliable than any client side (AJAX/image-based) method.  Sometimes, users will terminate navigation before your javascript can run, or your image can load (e.g., if they click a link, hit stop, close the browser), causing your statistics not to register for that request.  If you send the request server side, you can be sure it will always be sent.